# Eloquent Raw Subquery Get Count By User

Tags: mysql, eloquent

I have two Models: Users and VacationRequests. A user can have many vacation requests. Vacation requests have a 'requested_by' column, which holds the user's id, a date_requested column, and a 'decision' column.

I'd like to get a count of each user's pending vacation requests. The query below does a good job of seeing how many total pending vacation requests there are in the table, but I can't quite figure out how to query **how many outsanding requests for each user there are.**

```
$users = DB::table('users')
        ->leftJoin('vacation_requests', 'users.id', '=', 'vacation_requests.requested_by')
        ->select('users.*', DB::raw('(SELECT COUNT(vacation_requests.date_requested) FROM vacation_requests WHERE decision = "pending") AS outstanding_requests'))
        ->groupBy('id')
        ->get();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. **Make the models and add a relationship between them**

```php
# app/User.php
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    protected $table = 'users';

    public function vacation_requests()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(VacationRequest::class, 'requested_by');
    }
}
```

```php
# app/VacationRequest.php
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class VacationRequest extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'vacation_requests';

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'requested_by');
    }
}
```

2. **Use Eloquent to build the query and aggregate the count**

```php
use App\User;
...
$users = User::withCount(['vacation_requests as outstanding_requests' => function ($count) {
    $count->where('decision', 'pending');
}])->get();
```

Comment: Perfect. Thank you. I actually did have those models with those relationships and totally forgot about them. The withCount and constraint query example was very helpful.